# Type Conversion With Concepts

Tags: algorithm, types, set

I am implementing a compiler framework that allows for custom casts.

A concept in this situation is a set of types. For example, the `Integer` concept is the set of all signed and unsigned whole numbers, where as the `Boolean` concept consists of a single boolean type. It is known whether or not any given type is a member of a concept.

A custom cast is defined by an input concept and an output concept, meaning that any type that fits the input concept will be transformed to be a member of the output concept. Ex: I can define a cast that converts any `Integer` to a `Boolean`. I have it set up this way, as I don't have to define casts for every single member of `Integer` and rather just one.

In addition to these rules, casts can be chained. For example, `int&` can be converted to `bool` by first converting it to `int` and then to `bool`. However, the shortest "distance" is preferred. Meaning that if a cast is able to convert `int&` to `bool` directly, than it will be chosen (if multiple paths have this shortest distance than an error will be thrown, so this case shouldn't be considered).

The problem is that given a list of all possible casts and input type `T` and destination concept `C`, how do I find which casts to apply to `T` to get to `C`?

Set theory approach:
Given an item `T` and list of transformations that allows a member of a given set to become a member of another one, how do I find the path of minimum transformations to get to set `C`?

My Ideas:

My first one was to create a graph with each unique concept as vertices and casts as edges and apply a path finding algorthm. The only problem is that I don't know how to define the start and goal nodes.

My second idea is to just brute force a path by going through each possible cast for each intermediate concept. While this would work, would there be a potential approach with dynamic programming?

Comment: A breadth-first search is standard.  Doing breadth-first from both ends and meeting in the middle is a good optimization with many types. Adding some caching is also likely to be very important for performance.